# Set random background image once per session

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I'm totally new to jquery. I want to be able to set the header background image randomly. I don't want it to change each time the page is refreshed. Rather, I'd just like to set it once per session. I'm assuming I need to use a session cookie for this, but can't get it to work.

The following is what I have thatt works fine on a per-refresh basis. I just want to stop it changing on each refresh.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var randomImages = ['image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4', 'image5'];
var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomImages.length);
var imageFile = $('#imgpathname').val() + randomImages[rndNum] + ".jpg";
$("div#header").css({ background: "url(" + imageFile + ") no-repeat" });
});
```

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: I don't understand. How do you plan to know which image was selected in the first place? it is normal that on page refresh the code gets executed again.But is that again? NO. Because the page is getting loaded for the 'first time', since browser does not know if this is the same page or not. Unless you use some cookie or caching technique.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was assuming. I assume I need to wrap this in an if statement. If the session cookie exists, get the image name from it, otherwise do what's in the code above and create a session cookie. I'm just not sure how to get that bit to work!

Answer (score 1):

hi why dont you store your imageID in html5 storage objects such as sessionStorage/localStorage, visit  [Html5 Storage Doc](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)  to get more details. using this you can store intermediate values temporaryly/permanently locally and then access your values 
for storing values for a session

```
sessionStorage.getItem('label')
sessionStorage.setItem('value', 'label')
```

or store values permanently using

```
localStorage.getItem('label')
localStorage.setItem('value', 'label')
```

So you can store (temporarily) form data between multiple pages using html5 storage objects which u can even retain after reload..

Now in your case you can store image ID in sessionstorage and use it whenever page is refreshed so that same image is loaded per session.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.cookie.js will likely be able to help you here:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/

From the project page, creating a session cookie is as easy as:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

You can then read this cookie back on each page load.

```
$.cookie('the_cookie'); // => "the_value"
```

I hope that helps. As suggested above, HTML5 local storage can be used, but a session cookie is more widely supported.